# Rails 3.1 escape_javascript doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following Code:

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')"))
  end
```

When it runs it's supposed to duplicate the previous form field. When i click on my link to add a new field it just renders the HTML inline (it's been completely escaped and viewable). I found a previous question which said this was an issue with Rails 3.1.0rc2 but i'm running the current 3.1.0 release of rails. So i'm not sure if this something with my config or if the issue has reappeared in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')"))
```

to this

```
link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')", :remote => true)
```

I think* rails 3.1.x does the escaping automatically

Comment: @witharmshigh glad to be of some help